# Multiple pan gestures in a mixing console app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I would like my iPad mixing console app to be able to move multiple sliders simultaneously when a user touches them with multiple fingers, just like in real life.

I have already implemented my logic for a single pan gesture (UIPanGestureRecognizer). How do I add multiple-touch functionality in this case?

There is a requirement of iOS 5.1 compatibility.

**Edit:** for reference, here is what the gesture looks like on real-life mixing consoles:

[image]

Comment: Have you added the multiple recognisers? What happened? What is the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create separate gesture recognizers for each slider, e.g. assuming you had a collection outlet:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.sliders enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *slider, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
        [slider addGestureRecognizer:pan];
    }];
}
```

Then, the gesture recognizer would then handle each one individually (surprisingly, without needing to recognize them simultaneously with `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`):

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:gesture.view];

    gesture.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, translation.y);

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        CGRect frame = gesture.view.frame;
        frame.origin.y += translation.y;
        gesture.view.frame = frame;
        gesture.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case the sliders are just CALayers, not views, but I got the idea, thanks!